# 100m people, 1 household... Pronoun + singular or plural noun.

Tags: pronouns

> 100m people have no access to a water source within 1 mile of their household.

Should this sentence be reformulated? It implies 100m people share a household. Should it be *households*?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be wrong, either way. In this case the household is the abstract object, not a specific instance. In the abstract sense, they all do share the household. In the concrete sense, it would just be "houses".

Edit:

You should wonder, why the water source is singular, as well. Change the meaning to say that they do have *a water source* or *water sources* in 1 mile distance to their *household**s*** and it's ambiguous either way - Do they have all the same source or multiple sources each? The abstract sense can be understood to mean *at least one*.